# Not able to build the kernel driver natively

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am building the kernel on a test machine on which I have to finally insert the module.
This is my Makefile :

```
obj-m += my-driver-module.o

all:
         make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

But I am getting this error :

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.16-bone11/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I checked in the /lib/modules/4.4.16-bone11/ directory in the test machine and found build symbolically linked to the sources(path to my development machine) where I built the kernel for this test machine like this :

```
 build -> path-in-my-development_machine-kernel-location-for-test-machine>/bb-kernel/KERNEL
```

I downloaded the headers using this command : 
`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r and able to build the module with the same Makefile successfully but when I am trying to insert it it says :

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module my-driver-module.ko: Invalid module format
```

How can I resolve it. This driver works as expected when cross-compiled and inserted.

Comment: 1. Have you tried hard link instead? 2. Have you tried specifying path to dev machine in the `Makefile` (`/lib/modules/...` > `/path-to-dev/bb-kernel/KERNEL`)?

Comment: There is a mismatching between kernel on test machine and the kernel version used for beaglebone target.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs can you please post the example.Makefile is for building only the module in the test machine.

Comment: @LPs beaglebone I am building the kernel on the test machine itself.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood. Try to check headers version. Use `modinfo my-driver-module.ko` ans see if the output match the output of `uname -r`

Comment: @LPs How he can do that if he is not able to build the module?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs (s)he is not able to install the module. The module is well compiled.

Comment: @LPs Ok, sorry, this question describes two problems. I was referencing to the first one.